# First Integrals of the Following Hamiltonian

Tags: classical-mechanics, integrable-systems

I have a Hamiltonian

$$
H = \sum_{1\leq i < j \leq n} p_i p_j \frac{\sinh({\lambda} (q_i - q_j))}{\lambda^2},
$$
where ($\textbf{q},\textbf{p}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, and $\lambda$ is a free parameter non equal to zero.
For the reduction method I tried to guess the "first" first integral. Something like this
$$
I_{kl} = p_k p_l \frac{\sinh({\lambda} (q_k - q_l))}{\lambda^2}
$$
does not commute(in terms of poisson-braket) with Hamiltonian. Don't know what to do with this one. Any help would be appreciated.